# Library not loaded: @rpath/leveldb.framework/leveldb

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, leveldb

I recently added a couple embedded frameworks to my project and it seems like the cocoapods install and the builds happen without issue but when I try to run in the simulator I get this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/leveldb.framework/leveldb
  Referenced from: /Users/<me>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<app>/Build/Products/Development-iphonesimulator/<framework>.framework/<framework>
  Reason: image not found
```

I had never done embedded frameworks before with cocoapods dependencies so I am guessing i didn't specify something correctly or there is something wrong with the dynamic linker.

Here is my `Podfile`

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'D.A.P' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for D.A.P
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
pod 'MapboxGeocoder.swift'
pod 'MapboxNavigation'
pod 'WillowTreeScrollingTabController', :git => 'https://github.com/mhs2342/WillowTreeScrollingTabController.git'

target 'D.A.PTests' do
    inherit! :complete
end

target 'DAPDatabase' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end

target 'DAPModel' do 
    pod 'MapboxGeocoder.swift'
    pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
end

end

post_install do |installer| 
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = '' 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have added this framework in Build phases under sections

1.Link binary with Libraries and 2. Embed frameworks. 
[image]Please see attached screenshot

Comment: Would this be done in my framework build settings or my app target settings

Comment: your app's target settings

Comment: try clean and build maybe